# Fallo al cambiar la tipografía con StyledEditorKit en Java swing

Tags: java, java-swing, styled-components

Mi problema se encuentra en que al usar el método **FontFamilyAction de la clase StyledEditorKit el texto no cambia de fuente cuando debería hacerlo** de la misma forma que me funcionan los métodos FontSizeAction, BoldAction, ItalicAction ...

```
String[] fuentes_disponibles = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAvailableFontFamilyNames();
JComboBox estilo_letra = new JComboBox(fuentes_disponibles);

estilo_letra.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    Action fuente_actual = new StyledEditorKit.FontFamilyAction("cambio_fuente", (String)estilo_letra.getSelectedItem());
                    fuente_actual.actionPerformed(e);
                        
        }
                
});
```

pd: No quiero recurrir al método setFont() ya que no funciona cuando tienes el JTextPane en HTML.

Muchas gracias de antemano. Un saludo.

Comment: ya intentaste invalidar y repintar en un hilo de swingUtilities tras cambiar la fuente?

Comment: No. Soy novato en Swing, no se a que te refieres ? Haciendo uso de los métodos FontSizeAction y etc no me hizo falta crear un hilo.